# How to create target for makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

```
 Hello:
   g++ Hello.cc dep.o -o Hello

 dep.o: dep.cc dep.h
        g++ -c dep.cc
```

I am trying out this makefile,but I want the target to be "make Hello". How should I modify my makefile? It work when I typed "make".

Comment: For some reason my code is not show correctly even after I have edited it.

Comment: FTFY. Greetings are being filtered in code blocks :_) That is a bug

Comment: What error do you get if you type `make Hello`?

Comment: I get undefined reference to dep(int n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all the dependencies, recursively:

```
Hello: Hello.cc dep.o
        g++ -o $@ $+

dep.o: dep.cc dep.h
        g++ -c -o $@ $<
```

It would probably be better to add a separate compilation stage for `Hello.o`, but I'll stick with the format prescribed by the question. You should probably also add `$(CXXFLAGS)` and `$(LDFLAGS)` to the compilation and link stages, respectively, and replace `g++` by `$(CXX)`.

Comment: It complains missing seperator -- stop.

Comment: Make sure you use tabs, not spaces!